# python keyboard module doesn't detect key immediately

Tags: python

first of all:  my english is not very good so i hope you can understand me. second of all, i'm new to programming so, i just don't know a lot of things.
what i'm trying to do whit this code is to assign keys to directions and make the turtle go the direction i want with those keys i press. the problem i have with my code is that the keyboard module recognizes the first two keys and the turtle react immediately, but that doesn't happen to the third key (the "a") because i have to press it two times to make it work. i really hope someone can help me here!

```
import turtle
import keyboard

turtle.screensize(500, 500)
if keyboard.read_key() == "w":
turtle.setheading(90), turtle.forward(400)
elif keyboard.read_key() == "s":
turtle.setheading(270), turtle.forward(400)
elif keyboard.read_key() == "a":
turtle.setheading(180), turtle.forward(400)
else:
""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if keyboard.read_key() == "w":
    ...
elif keyboard.read_key() == "s":
    ...
elif keyboard.read_key() == "a":
   ...
```

This is your problem.  Each time you call `read_key()`, it reads ANOTHER key from the keyboard.

So this code reads a key and compares it to "w".  If it's not equal it reads another key and compares it to "s".  And so on...

Instead of doing that, you want to read a key ONCE, save its value, and use that value for ALL the comparisons:

```
key = keyboard.read_key()
if key == "w":
    ...
elif key == "s":
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@John Gordon's answer is great, I just wanted to add something. Often `keyboard.read_key()` is not used, since it can be hard to clear keyboard input after pressing a key, and there is usually a more efficient way to do it with the `keyboard` library.

We can use `keyboard.add_hotkey()` to allow our program to call a function whenever a key is pressed. Here is a simple example:

```
#after importing turtle, keyboard, and doing whatever you want to do

def w_pressed():
    #do something when the key w is pressed

def a_pressed():
    #do something when the key a is pressed

def s_pressed():
    #do something when the key s is pressed

def d_pressed():
    #do something when the key d is pressed

keyboard.add_hotkey('w', w_pressed) #bind the key w to the function w_pressed
keyboard.add_hotkey('a', a_pressed) #bind the key a to the function a_pressed
keyboard.add_hotkey('s', s_pressed) #bind the key s to the function s_pressed
keyboard.add_hotkey('d', d_pressed) #bind the key d to the function d_pressed
```

One big advantage of this code is it doesn't require a loop, so this code will always work even after the first time. It also allows you to get rid of `if` and `elif` statements, which improves the general organization of the code. I will note that the code here is a little repetitive. There might be better functions, so make sure to look at the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/README.md).